# Div to set in center not working

Tags: html, css

On this site `deutschepornohd.com` is a div element of post:

```
<div class="heatmapthemead-article">
```

and I want to make it centered on every screen width, especially in mobile.

I set to it perent div:

```
<div id="heatmapthemead-the-content-container" role="main">

text-align:center!important;
```

but on small screens where it must show only two or one such div, it is not centered. Is it possible to make it centered?

Comment: have you tried @media queries? https://devdocs.io/css/media_queries/using_media_queries

Comment: yes but id shows centered inline text and not whole div

Comment: Are you allowed to use flexbox?

Comment: yes, but why///

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;